# How to set root directory for webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am configuring webpack for react storybook and I am having issues with the import statements paths. When I normally run my app, I have a path like this:

`import { constructURLName } from "src/shared/utilities/stringManipulation";`

I am using the [reactQL boilerplate](http://reactql.org) and it is configured so that it will return the proper module based on the src folder. How can I replicate that in storybook? Storybook currently tries to look for that stringManipulation file here:

`/Users/me/development/reactQL/node_modules/src/shared/utilities/stringManipulation`

So it needs to go up one directory based on my layout:

```
node_modules
src
  pages
  ...
  shared
    utilities
      stringManipulation
```

This is what my rule looks like for  js/jsx files:

```
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
              babelrc: false,
              presets: [
                ["env", { modules: false, exclude: ["transform-regenerator"] }],
                "react"
              ],
              plugins: [
                "transform-object-rest-spread",
                "syntax-dynamic-import",
                "transform-regenerator",
                "transform-class-properties",
                "transform-decorators-legacy"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

How can I properly set the src directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can use `resolve.modules`.

```
const path = require('path');
const config = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way using `resolve.alias`, assume that the folder to run Webpack is the parent folder of `src`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
};
```

It's possible to use `~` or `@` or whatever aliases but not the slash `/`, that slash can't be alias, it causes some problems: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/854

It's because Webpack runs on Node.js and that slash `/` is already the root dir in *nix systems: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/854#issuecomment-304763050